# how to make a fog effect or blur effect in canvas with js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I'm using javascript and `THREE.js` 3d engine,

and I want to do a fog effect,

here's an example http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_terrain_fog.html

but it only support `WebGL`,

so is there any way to simulate `fog effect`, or a `blur effect` with javascript and canvas?

thanks alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three.js *is* WebGL. The example you're looking at is created by the same person who made three.js.

Three.js supports fog already with `scene.fog`.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-THREE.Fog

---

*below is for people that searched for fog/blur in Canvas looking for 2D*

There are a bunch of places that have [implemented various blur effects](http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html). The [pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/) library has a lot of such effects implemented.

Fog is something different, though. There isn't a universal definition and it really depends on what you're looking for. One way would be to set the `globalAlpha` of the canvas to something like `0.3` and then draw [perlin noise](http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2011/12/perlin-noise-in-javascript_31.html) on the locations that you want "fog" to appear. Note that the color gradient of the noise that you most likely want is transparent to dark gray.