# Creating a lantern effect (or highlight/fog of war effect)

Tags: html, css

I want to know if there is another, better way, to achieve a lantern effect (or highlight/fog of war effect)(or how is it called).

Now I achieve this effect using 4 divs for each side of the screen but I want to know if it can be done in another way or if there is a library for this.

I want this functionality to create a tutorial for my website.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#a1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

#a2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 50px;
  left: 150px;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
}

#a3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 150px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  height: calc(100% - 150px);
}

#a4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}

#b {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Jacksonville_FL_Dyal-Upchurch_Bldg01.jpg/1200px-Jacksonville_FL_Dyal-Upchurch_Bldg01.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
  <div id="a1"></div>
  <div id="a2"></div>
  <div id="a3"></div>
  <div id="a4"></div>
  <div id="b">highlight this zone</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Three.js apparently has this effect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938965/how-to-make-a-fog-effect-or-blur-effect-in-canvas-with-js

Comment: You could move the image to be a background image. Perhaps a wrapper with a background image with gradient and the containers have a background image without the gradient. Something like this perhaps? https://jsfiddle.net/eq5ajkg7/

Answer (score 0):

If a simple shape (rectangle or ellipsis) is sufficient for the highlight area, you can use a simple overlay `div` with gradient background.

If you need a rectangle area, you can use [`conic-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/conic-gradient):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  left: -70px;
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  background:
    conic-gradient(from 0deg at 150px 150px, rgba(245, 245, 245, .7), 90deg, rgba(245, 245, 245, .7), 90deg, transparent),
    conic-gradient(from 90deg at 100px 150px, rgba(245, 245, 245, .7), 90deg, rgba(245, 245, 245, .7), 90deg, transparent),
    conic-gradient(from 180deg at 100px 100px, rgba(245, 245, 245, .7), 90deg, rgba(245, 245, 245, .7), 90deg, transparent),
    conic-gradient(from 270deg at 150px 100px, rgba(245, 245, 245, .7), 90deg, rgba(245, 245, 245, .7), 90deg, transparent);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Jacksonville_FL_Dyal-Upchurch_Bldg01.jpg/1200px-Jacksonville_FL_Dyal-Upchurch_Bldg01.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

If you need an ellipsis area, you can use [`radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  left: -70px;
  position: relative;
  top: -70px;
}

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle at 120px 120px, transparent 23px, rgba(245, 245, 245, .7) 25px);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Jacksonville_FL_Dyal-Upchurch_Bldg01.jpg/1200px-Jacksonville_FL_Dyal-Upchurch_Bldg01.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

But if you need a more complex shape, like a star, or if you need multiple highlight areas, this method is not suitable. I think then you could use something like the [`mask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) or [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) methods.